# I can't read a database on mysql because of wrong syntax in the database name, but the database reads on other platforms like DBmaria

Tags: mysql

Hi please I am new to mysql and I'd love to know how to access a database with the name 'c-factory'. It seems mysql does not read it because of the '-' sign. I've been able to load it on dbmaria but I don't seem to be able to do it with mysql

```
SELECT      * FROM     c-factory
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-factory' at line 4  0.000 sec```

Comment: Just surround the table name with backticks: `SELECT * FROM \`c-factory\``

Comment: *I've been able to load it on dbmaria*: I doubt that MariaDB supports hypens in unquoted identifiers. The query you were running probably had these backticks too.

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html